# How to retrieve a different attribute from a row with multiple different and repeated values into a new column?

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
att1 att2
| a | 1 |
| a | 2 |
| b | 2 |
| b | 3 |
| c | 1 |
| c | 2 |
| c | 2 |
```

And I need the different record of att2 for the duplicate value on att1 to be grouped into a new column like this

```
att1 att2 att3
| a | 1 | 2 |
| b | 2 | 3 |
| c | 1 | 2 |
```

I tried to pivot, I tried to self join, but I can't seem to find the query to separate the values like this. Can someone please help me? Thanks

Comment: Seems like a PIVOT to me. What happens if there is a third attribute though?

Comment: Post what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a dynamic pivot query like below
<kbd>[see demo link](http://rextester.com/KJNBGQ19780)</kbd>

```
create table tt (att1 varchar(10), att2 int)
insert into tt values
('a',1)
,('a',2)
,('b',2)
,('b',3)
,('c',1)
,('c',2)
,('c',2)
go

declare @q varchar(max), @cols varchar(max)
set @cols
     = STUFF((
          SELECT distinct ',' + 
               QUOTENAME('att '+
                         cast(1+ row_number()  over (partition by att1 order by att2 ) as varchar(max))
                        ) 
            FROM (select distinct att1,att2 from tt)tt --note this distinct
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @q=
'select 
  att1,'+ @cols +
' from
(
    select 
       att1,att2,
       ''att ''+
         cast(1+row_number()  over (partition by att1 order by att2 ) as varchar(max))  as r
    from 
       (select distinct att1,att2 from tt)tt 
)I
pivot
( 
    max(att2)   
    for r in ('+@cols+')
 )piv'

 exec(@q)
```

Answer (score 0):

Any query like this always smells like report formatting, rather than genuine data requirement, which should probably be done in a reporting tool rather than a database. But as with all things it is possible with enough code.

This should work for you.

```
create table #t (att1 nvarchar(max) ,att2 int);

insert #t select 'a', 1 union all select 'a', 2;
insert #t select 'b', 2 union all select 'b', 3;
insert #t select 'c', 1 union all select 'c', 2 union all select 'c', 2;

select att1, 1 as att2, 2 as att3 from 
(
    select att1, att2, row_number() over (partition by att1 order by att1, att2) as r
    from (select distinct att1, att2 from #t) as x 
) src
pivot ( avg(att2) for r in ([1],[2])) p;

drop table #t;
```

The first step is to get the distinct values in your table, and then sort and group them by att1. I'm doing this with a `row_number()` command, which looks like this:

```
select att1, att2, row_number() over (partition by att1 order by att1, att2) as r
from (select distinct att1, att2 from #t) as x ;

att1 attr2 r
a    1     1
a    2     2
b    2     1
b    3     2
c    1     1
c    2     2
```

From there the pivot command transforms rows into columns. The catch with the pivot command is that the names of those new columns need to be data driven; during your `row_number` command you could provide better names, or you can alias them as I have done here.

Finally, this only works when there are only two values to pivot. To add more, modify the `for r in ([1], [2])` line to include e.g. 3, 4, etc.